# Can we pass pointers in printf?

Tags: c, pointers, printf

In the following code, we pass pointer to a string and it works fine but it doesn't works for pointer to an integer. I want to know why ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char *astring = "afdv";
     printf("%s",astring);
    int a;
    a = 1000;
    int *ptr = &a;
    printf("\n%d", ptr);
}
```

Comment: No you pass a *single* `char` value (which is then converted to an `int`). If you mean you pass a pointer when printing a string, then that's something very different because `printf` knows how to handle those pointers with the `"%s"` format.

Comment: Please demonstrate where you are passing a pointer to a string. You aren't even passing a *string*... also, try `printf( "%p\n", ptr )`. Then read the manual on `printf()`.

Comment: In the first case, "%c" expects a single character, and you pass it a dereferenced character pointer (*astring), which is a single character. It is not a "pointer to a string" as you say, that would be &astring. All is well. "%d" expects an integer value, not a pointer. If you dereference it (*ptr), then that would work.

Comment: Don't just smash around with wild experiments. Read the documentation carefully and see what values have to be paired up with particular placeholders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first `printf` you did NOT send a pointer. You de-referenced the pointer and hence, you are actually sending a character. Likewise if you want to print an integer, send `*ptr`, the dereferenced value of the integer pointer.

I'm guessing the source of your confusion to be this-

```
 printf("%s", string_ptr);
```

perfectly prints the **string value** instead of the **pointer value** but

```
printf("%d", integer_ptr);
```

prints the **pointer value** instead of the **integer value**.

This is because the way `printf` is implemented. When it sees a `%s` in the format string, it considers the corresponding parameter as a pointer to a NULL-terminated string. And goes looking for the value of that string at the address contained in the pointer.

But when it sees a `%d`, it considers the corresponding parameter as an integer value and prints it out directly.

The change in behavior is because types like integer, floats etc are smaller and finite in size and can be passed to `printf` as values directly. But a string can be arbitrarily large in size. So it makes sense to pass it as a pointer and let `printf` go find the actual value using the pointer.

Comment: Yes you are right.. that was exactly what I wanted to ask.. I put the wrong code here before.

Answer (score 1):

Because the language specification says so.

The `%s` conversion specifier expects its corresponding argument to have type `char *`; `printf` will then print out the sequence of characters starting at that address until it sees the string terminator.

The `%d` conversion specifier expects its corresponding argument to have type `int`; `printf` will then print out the text representation of that value as a signed decimal integer.

Check your handy C reference manual for the complete list of conversion specifiers and the types of arguments they expect.  If you don't have a handy C reference manual, my preferred one has been [C: A Reference Manual](http://careferencemanual.com) since the late 1980s, although the current edition only covers up to C99.

If you use `%d` and pass something that *isn't* an integer, then the behavior is *undefined*.  The compiler isn't required to yell at you for passing an argument of the wrong type.  If you run the code, anything may happen.  In practice, you'll usually get garbled output.  If you pass something that isn't a pointer for `%s`, you may get a runtime error.